# Fetch total number of repositories of a package type in Artifactory.

Tags: rest, api, artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

Are there any API’s to fetch the total number of repositories of a particular package type in JFrog Artifactory? 
For eg: Total number of maven repositories, total npm repositories etc. I need the total number of each repository based on their package type.

Answer (score 4):

That seems like a very specific and not often all that useful feature, so there's no API specifically for it. You can use [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetRepositories) to get a list of all repositories, and then for each repository in the list you can use [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RepositoryConfiguration) to get its configuration (including its package type). You could write a script that does this and then counts the number of repositories for each package type.

Keep in mind the difference between virtual, remote, and local repositories, and whether you want some of those to be counted separately or left out.

EDIT
/api/repositories api now have the 2 abilities:

1. it returns the packageType parameter.
2. it can filter by packageType query param.

example:

```
curl localhost:8081/artifactory/api/repositories?packageType=Generic


[ {
  "key" : "example-repo-local",
  "description" : "Example artifactory repository",
  "type" : "LOCAL",
  "url" : "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/example-repo-local",
  "packageType" : "Generic"
} ]
```

So, you can do this call and count the results.

with jq (commandline JSON parser):

```
curl localhost:8081/artifactory/api/repositories?packageType=Generic | jq length
```

Available from Artifactory 6.2.0

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you. Yes, this really helps. We are currently using Artifactory version 5.11 and plan to upgrade to the latest version soon. So I guess, we’d be able to make use of this feature then.